# Type declaration in NextJS project

Tags: typescript, next.js, typescript-typings

I am new to both NextJS and typescript. I am creating a project for practice and I was wondering will it a good idea to store all my type definitions in one file like `global.d.ts`? or keeping all the type definitions in one file will effect the project performance? if so, what is the proper way to store my type definition when working with typescript?

I was trying a Next JS project with Typescript.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your type definitions should be stored where they are being used. If you have a users domain for example then put the user type in that folder.